# Should DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument bubble?

Tags: javascript, events, dom, mutation-events

I've been always thinking that DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument/DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument events should not bubble, and for me that made enough sence. However, just recently I looked into specification once again and found out that in one location it says these events should not bubble ([Complete list of event types](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/events.html#Events-EventTypes-complete)), while in other location is says they should ([DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/events.html#event-DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument) and [DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/events.html#event-DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument)).

I've also looked up on the Internet and found several implementations, all of them are different in the behavior implemented.

The question is: Should these events actually bubble ot not? What do you think make more sence?

**Update**: Found out that in [DOM-Level-2-Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html) specification there is no ambiguity since it olny mentions these events in a single location.

**Update 2**: This question was asked in order to validate the behavior of these events in the [Ample SDK](http://www.clientside.ru/) Ajax Framework that aims to implement all standards-based technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with ‘No’, as per Level 2 Events, which is a proper Recommendation that has been around a long time and has errata that do not include anything to do with this. DOM Level 3 Events is only a Working Group Note and still WD, which is a bit unsatisfactory all round.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you already discovered that they should not bubble. But it is a moot point for a practical developer because they are not supported by IE, which still holds ~80% of the market. :-(